# R: grep exactly using a character vector with multiple patterns

Tags: r

How to match `t1` with `t2` using the `grep` function?

**t1**

```
t1 %>% head()

[1] "ITGB4"   "GPER1"   "FAM162A" "S100A2"  "MBNL1"   "RNASE11"
```

**t2**

```
t2 %>% head(10)

 [1] ""                                               
 [2] ""                                               
 [3] "RP1-45C12.1;RP1-127D3.4;RP1-127D3.4;RP1-127D3.4"
 [4] "PRKAG2;PRKAG2;PRKAG2"                           
 [5] ""                                               
 [6] "AC022201.4"                                     
 [7] "TLK1"                                           
 [8] ""                                               
 [9] ""                                               
 [10] ""
```

I tried `grep(paste(t1,sep = "", collapse = "|"), t2, value = T) %>% unique()`, but the outputs are some gene symbles that are not in t1 or not exactly the same as the gen symbles in t1.

Any good ideas about how to match t1 and t2?

Comment: You could use `t2[sapply(strsplit(t2, ";"), function(x) length(intersect(x, t1)) > 0)]`.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem? I guess you work with Protein IDs or Gene names within MaxQuant, and I solved it the way I presented below. You might have to convert `t1` and `t2` into a vector first.

Comment: Thank you Scarabee! your answer also solved my problem.

Comment: @drmariod, I was trying to match gene names from publications with our array data, thank you for your prompt help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create all versions of the string. Only this ID, ID at the beginning, ID at the end and ID in the middle...

```
search_string <- paste0(c('^',';',';','^'), 
       rep(t1, each=4), 
       c('$',';','$',';'), collapse='|')
candidates <- grep(search_string, t2)
```

Comment: It's working well, I didn't realise that I need to match ";", thank you so much!

Comment: Later, I found long regular expression patterns in `grep` was not accepted (e.g 25KB), so `search_string` could not be too long I suppose.

Comment: You can also use `%in%` instead of `grep`. But for this you need to do some formatting first. Since you need to ungroup your `t2` first, you need to find the correct group after matching. One approach could be to search block wise with only 300 IDs from `t1`.